# Is it possible to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2012 R2?

I have the developer edition installation files.

Comment: I could give you the link to answer your specific question but I think it would be a better learning experience for you to find it yourself.

Comment: Yes you can do ,search hardware and software requirement for installing sql server 2008 r2 and then refer to MS books online

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Microsoft answers this in [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.105).aspx#DEx64).

To find the article I entered the search term:

sql server 2008 r2 compatibility

into [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20server%202008%20r2%20compatibility).